# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string on PDF blob data from Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on some code to read out the BODY field from a Dynamics CRM Email attachment and decode the Base64 string back to a file to write to the file system.

This process seems to work fine on image files like .PNG etc, Excel .xls etc, but when i try and convert a PDF file to a byte array in C# i get the error:

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string on the Convert.FromBase64String() line.

```
var binaryData = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test\stream.txt");
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(binaryData);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test\file.pdf", byteArray);
```

I've tried storing the binarydata in a file and reading it in as well as just defining a C# string with the content.  As i say, it works on other file types but just not PDF.

I found another reference to the same issue, 
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a28e106-3715-42b9-a743-9e5207a02540/problem-while-decoding-the-body-field-of-activitymimeattachment-entity?forum=crm

But the solution was just to loop through a byte array and write each byte individually, it still ends up in a corrupt PDF file that wont open in Acrobat.

Ultimately, i will read the binaryData in from a database field or through the CRM API, but i just wanted to test the theory first and I seem to be good on all attachment types except PDF...

Comment: One post i saw said try padding the binary data before converting to a byte array.. i tried something like the below, and i get past the conversion error but the PDF is still corrupt:              string dummyData = b.Trim().Replace(" ", "+");
            if (dummyData.Length % 4 > 0) dummyData = dummyData.PadRight(dummyData.Length + 4 - dummyData.Length % 4, '=');
            byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(dummyData);

Comment: Dealing with bytes and dealing with text are completely different tasks in programming. When you convert text to bytes (and vice versa), the program will format the bytes based on assumptions about encoding, byte order, and localization, to name a few examples. Unless it's absolutely required to convert the file into text, you should treat the file as a byte array from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess of mine, I have no idea if this works.

Sometimes the character encoding is wrong because text files may have a BOM ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) and just arbitrary binary data can interfere with it. You can force the encoding to ASCII by reading the data in as a binary `byte[]` and then converting it into ASCII as shown here:

```
byte[] data;

data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\test\stream.txt");
string base64 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test\file.pdf", data);
```

Let's see if this solves anything.

Comment: thanks, i did try the ASCII encoding thing.. in the end my original stream was bad on files bigger than 32kb.. as it was working on small files, i wrongly assumed my methodology was right.. but it wasnt.. thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

what i learnt is that the value in the BODY field in the SQL table only holds 32kb of the blob stream.. i have no idea where the reset of it lives. i asked around and every one said 'getting from SQL is not supported way'.. even though reading data from CRM SQL Filtered views IS supported...

so when i was testing with small PNG and JPG files it was fine, but if i tried a bigger file it would not work, i clicked when all the largest streams were all 32kb when saved to file system.

in the end i solved it by getting the attachment stream data via the CRM SDK instead of from SQL in the FilteredEmailAttachment view in SQL

```
   var attachments = (from a in cc.CRMContext.ActivityMimeAttachments where a.ActivityId == email.ActivityId select a).ToList();
                foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Body);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test\temp\" + attachment.FileName, byteArray);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an error arising from the validation logic, maybe you could check if there are white spaces in the base64 data and if there are some, replace them with '+'. Copying the problem scenario with the solution I am talking about.

```
var binaryData = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\test\stream.txt");
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(binaryData.Replace(' ', '+'));
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test\file.pdf", byteArray);
```

Has worked for me in the past.